# I have a C library of related functions with different prefixes. How can derived C++ classes call them without repeating code?

Tags: c++, oop, wrapper

I am working with a driver library talking to hardware with different model numbers.  The API that comes with this hardware has a different library for different major versions, even though many of the interactions are the same. For example, if I am talking to a 4000 series device, I would call

```
handle_t handle;
dv4000_OpenDevice(&handle);
dv4000_DoSomething(handle);
dv4000_Close(handle);
```

and for a 5000 series device

```
handle_t handle;
dv5000_OpenDevice(&handle);
dv5000_DoSomething(handle);
dv5000_Close(handle);
```

So now I want to create a `Device` base class and `Device_Series4k` and `Device_Series5k` derived classes.  How can I implement this without copying most of the implementation and swapping out the function calls?  Note that the API is not  *exactly* the same for the different series, so having a make rule that generates a source file with the name substitutions at compile time won't work (although doing so with just the common parts might be feasible).

General C++ solutions with templates or macros would be ideal, but Makefile/shell tricks for Linux/gcc would work too.

EDIT
One example that works in a very limited context might be:

```
class Device{
public: 
  typedef uint16_t handle_t;
  typedef int (*Opener)(handle_t*);
  typedef int (*Closer)(handle_t);

  Device(Opener open, Closer close) : _handle(0), _close(close)
  { open(&_handle); }

  ~Device(){ _close(_handle); } 

private:
  handle_t _handle;
  Closer _close;
};


class Device_Series4k : public Device { 
public:
  Device_Series4k : Device(dv4000_OpenDevice, dv4000_ClosDevice) {}
};
```

I could do the same with templates and an additional layer of abstraction.  It's still a net benefit if I want to e.g. do error checking or a bunch of common initialization/allocation type things after calling open.  But it quickly becomes unbearably messy if I need to provide 20 different DoSomething signatures.

Comment: Your two examples are both for the `4000` series device...

Comment: TBH, If the `API`s differ then it is hard to imagine how you could be generic about this without the risk of things falling apart when the next version is published. Especially if the sequence of operations change unexpectedly.

Comment: The short answer is: you can't. C++ does not work this way. You might be able to cobble something together with external scripts that will spew out the robo-generated C++ code for you, and have the compiler swallow it.

Comment: @Galik: You are right about future version changes, but I am confident some things won't change, like Open and Close always being the first calls I need to make.  Just being able to wrap those calls and carry around the handle with proper RAII would make this library more useful to me (I can stick a Device in a shared_ptr and not worry about cleanup), but even that little is not straightforward

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you almost certainly want a DeviceHandle class for RAII purposes:

```
typedef void (*CloseDeviceFn)(handle_t);
class DeviceHandle {
    handle_t val;
    CloseDeviceFn close;
public:
    explicit DeviceHandle(handle_t v, CloseDeviceFn closeFn) noexcept : val(v), close(closeFn) {}
    DeviceHandle(DeviceHandle&& rhs) noexcept : val(rhs.release()) {}
    DeviceHandle& operator=(DeviceHandle&& rhs) noexcept {reset(rhs.release()); return *this;}
    ~DeviceHandle() noexcept {reset(nullptr);}

    handle_t get() noexcept {return val;}
    void reset(handle_t v) noexcept {if (val != nullptr) close(val); val = v;}
    handle_t release() noexcept {handle_t t = val; val = nullptr; return t;}
};
```

For APIs that *don't* change, what you ask for is trivial:

```
class Device {
public:
    virtual ~Device() {}; //classes with any virtual methods should have a virtual destructor
    virtual void DoSomething();
};

class Device_Series4k: public Device {
    DeviceHandle handle;
public:
    explicit Device_Series4k(handle_t handle_)
    : handle_(handle, &dv4000_Close) {
        dv4000_OpenDevice(handle.get());
    }
    void DoSomething() {dv4000_DoSomething(handle.get());}
};
```

For APIs that change, then you probably have to have versioned base classes:

```
class DeviceApis {
public:
    virtual ~Device() {};
    virtual int version() = 0;
    virtual void DoSomething() = 0;
};
class Device4000Apis: public Device {
public:
    virtual void DoNewerConcept();
};
```

And then `Device_Series5k` would extend `Device4000Apis`, and you'd have to do nonsense like this:

```
DeviceApis myDevice = ...
Device4000Apis deviceAtLeast4000 = dynamic_cast<Device4000Apis>(myDevice);
if (deviceAtLeast4000 != nullptr) {
    deviceAtLeast4000.doNewerConcept();
} else {
    log.d("device doesn't support concept");
}
```

If you *really* want to avoid the copy-paste, you can fake it with templates:

```
template<OpenDeviceFn openDeviceFn,
         CloseDeviceFn closeDeviceFn,
         DoSomethingFn doSomethingFn>
class DeviceImpl: public Device {
    DeviceHandle handle;
public:
    explicit DeviceImpl(handle_t handle_)
    : handle(handle_, closeDeviceFn) {
        openDeviceFn(handle.get());
    }
    void DoSomething() {doSomethingFn(handle.get());}
};
typedef DeviceImpl<dv4000_OpenDevice, dv4000_Close, dv4000_DoSomething> Device_Series4k;
```

As demonstrated here: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f6974f463644da50

Or another option is to make a `DeviceType` class that has members that are pointers to the various methods, and each `Device` has a pointer to the `DeviceType`, which would allow you to sort of emulate the template option without actually using templates, which keeps implementations out of headers, but also interferes with in-lining.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but in your first code block, wouldn't the Device_Series5k be a complete copy/paste of Device_Series4k replacing all dv4000 with dv5000?

Comment: You can sort of do it with less copy paste via templates I suppose, but otherwise, yes.

Comment: @thegreatemu: Added a template option, which minimizes copy-paste. Also corrected a few compiler errors.